# PostgreSQL syntax error at or near INT

Tags: sql, postgresql, int, syntax-error

I made a script to create a database with PostgreSQL.
So I copy in my script, click "Analyze & Explain" in pgAdmin4 and I have no clue why it says I have a **syntax error at or near 'INT'** on idSituationFamiliale.

I really can't see what's wrong...

```
--Personnes
--
CREATE TABLE SITUATION_FAMILIALE (
    idSituationFamiliale INT NOT NULL,
    intituleSituationFamiliale VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(idSituationFamiliale)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query is fine if you RUN it. It is wrong if you EXPLAIN / ANALYZE it.
The [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-explain.html) says that you can explain a `CREATE TABLE AS`, not a pure `CREATE TABLE` statement. While the former contains a `SELECT` statement that can be explained/analyzed, the later has nothing to be explained/analyzed and fails on the 1st field, regardless of its name or type.

Comment: Okay, I will try to run the script as such asap ^^
Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

You should be using integer as opposed to int.

e.g

```
--Personnes
--
CREATE TABLE SITUATION_FAMILIALE (
idSituationFamiliale INTEGER NOT NULL,
intituleSituationFamiliale VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(idSituationFamiliale)
);
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response ^^
Unfortunately it doesn't change anything :/

Comment: How about:

    `--Personnes
    --
    CREATE TABLE SITUATION_FAMILIALE (
    idSituationFamiliale INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    intituleSituationFamiliale VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    );`

Comment: `int` is a valid alias for `integer` in Postgres

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't realised.

Comment: Still the same problem :/

Comment: See the answer from @JGH :-)